# What is the smallest number of coins I could have?

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

> A country has 6 coins of the following denominations: 1 cent, 2 cents, 4 cents, 10 cents, 20 cents and 40 cents. Using the coins I have, I can pay exactly for any amount up to and including 200 cents. What is the smallest number of coins I could have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947867/find-the-least-number-of-coins-required-that-can-make-any-change-from-1-to-99-ce

Comment: I am pretty sure this has been asked before. Probably more than once.

Comment: Thanks Tiwari but that is a different question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a 1 cent coin so you can make 1.  To make 3, you need either a 1 and a 2 or three ones.  The first uses fewer coins.  Keep going.

Comment: I did but the answer i got was 9 but the right answer is 10

Comment: What 9 coins do you think work?

Comment: @ABC:  I don't see nine that work, either.  You need four coins below $10$, a $10$, a $20$, and four $40$s

Comment: Sorry, its not 9. I got 11. 5x40c, 1x20c, 1x10c, 2x4c, 1x2c, 1x1c.

Comment: @ABC:  You don't need the last $40$.  The smaller coins can give you $40$, so you can reach $200$ without it.

Comment: Yes i just realised that. Thanks alot! Sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a **knapsack problem**.

If we are given a positive integer $n \leq 200$, then we solve the following **integer program** (IP) to determine how many coins of each denomination to pick

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + 2 x_2 + 4 x_3 + 10 x_4 + 20 x_5 + 40 x_6 = n\\ & x_i \in \mathbb N\end{array}$$

where the decision variables are

- $x_1$ is the number of $1$ cent coins.
- $x_2$ is the number of $2$ cent coins.
- $x_3$ is the number of $4$ cent coins.
- $x_4$ is the number of $10$ cent coins.
- $x_5$ is the number of $20$ cent coins.
- $x_6$ is the number of $40$ cent coins.

Comment: How on earth does this qualify as an answer?

Comment: @fleablood How does that qualify as constructive criticism?